# Random Card Selection Algorithm Comparison

Tags: probability, sampling, games

I'm working on a programming [puzzle/challenge](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/24r50l/552014_161_easy_blackjack/) for fun, and had a question about whether or not two approaches for doing random selection are equivalent.

Lets say I have a class `Deck` which contains initially a collection of 52 cards.  Then I have a class `Shoe` which holds a collection of `Deck`.

Would the following approaches be statistically equivalent?

Approach 1:  Select a random `Deck` in `Shoe`.  Then from selected deck, select a random card.

Approach 2: Pull all the cards from all the `Deck`s in `Shoe` into a single collection, and randomly select a Card from that collection?

In use, the selection would be done many times, with the selected card being removed from the `Deck` / `Shoe`.

Comment: In thinking about this, I'm fairly certain they are not equivalent.  If I somehow had a `Shoe` with 10 `Decks`, and one of those `Deck` had exactly one Card, but the rest had say 50 Cards, approach 1 would yield a 1/10 probability of selecting the single card in the small `Deck` vs approach 2's probability of 1/501.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent for the first card drawn but not for the second or later cards until you replace the drawn cards.

As an example consider two $52$-card decks and the probability that the first two cards drawn are both the Ace of Spades:

1. The probability the first card drawn is an Ace of Spades is $\frac1{52}$.  The conditional probability that the second card is also an Ace of Spades is $\frac{1}{2} \times 0 +\frac{1}{2} \times  \frac{1}{52} = \frac{1}{104}$. So the probability of a pair of Aces of Spades is $\frac{1}{5408}$.
2. The probability the first card drawn is an Ace of Spades is $\frac1{52}$.  The conditional probability that the second card is also an Ace of Spades is $\frac{1}{103}$. So the probability of a pair of Aces of Spades is $\frac{1}{5356}$.